# CentOS上で開くことのできないファイルができる条件

Tags: java, linux

CentOS、JBossEAP環境のJavaアプリケーションを作っています。
このアプリケーションにはファイルを出力する機能があります。
Aspose.Cellsという製品を使って、PDFやExcelを生成します。
おおむね、以下のような流れの処理です。

1. `File.createTempFile()`を使って一時ファイルのパスを作る
2. 一時ファイルの`FileOutputStream`を作る (`new FileOutputStream()`)
3. Aspose.Cellsにこの`FileOutputStream`や流し込むデータなどを渡し、帳票ファイルの中身を書き込んでもらう
4. `FileOutputStream`を`close`
5. 一時ファイルの`FileInputStream`を作る (`new FileInputStream()`)
6. 一時ファイルから永続化のためDBにファイルをコピーする

この処理において、なぜか「パスワード付きPDF」や「パスワード付きExcel」を作った場合のみ、5で`FileNotFoundException`（メッセージ：許可されていない操作です）が発生します。
パスワード付きか否かは、Aspose.Cellsへ渡すオプションであり、少なくともこちらで書いているコードは、このオプション設定以外は全く同じです。

更に調査を進めたところ、問題の一時ファイルについては、CentOS上からroot権限でもって`cp`コマンドや`strings`コマンドでアクセスしようとした場合にも、「許可されていない操作です」というエラーが発生することが分かりました。
`move`や`rm`はできます。
`move`したファイルを`cp`しようとしても、「許可されていない操作です」になります。

分かっているのはここまでです。
もちろん最終的にはこれを解決する必要があるのですが、まず知りたいのは、このファイルがどのような状態のものなのか、です。
ファイル自体の権限を確認したところ、`rw-r--r--`です。
少なくとも読み込みはできる権限だと思うのですが、なぜあのようなエラーが起きるのでしょうか？

同じディレクトリ内にある他のファイル（パスワード無しのPDFなど）は問題が起きないので、ディレクトリではなくファイル自体の問題ではないかと推測していますが。
なお、この一時ファイルの生成に使っているディレクトリは、`/tmp`です。
`/tmp`ディレクトリの権限設定は、`rwxrwxrwt`です。

Linuxのファイルアクセス権限周りに疎いので、まずキーワードだけでも、この状態のファイルを表す説明を探しています。

====================================================
追加で調査した内容がありますので追記します。

問題のエラーが起きるファイルですが、Aspose.Cells以外の手段で作成したパスワード付きPDFでも発生します。
更に、そのPDFファイルをバイナリエディタで開き、ファイル先頭の"%PDF-"の部分のみを削除したところ、エラーが起きなくなりました。

Comment: Unix 系のファイルシステムにおいて、ディレクトリに対する権限とファイルに対する権限で若干意味が異なります。当該ファイルが `/home/alice/dir/file.txt` であるとしたら `dir` のパーミッションと `file.txt` のパーミッションの両方を確認して追記いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 現在、その権限を確認できないのですが、「移動や削除はできるが、コピーや読み込みはできない」という権限設定があるということでしょうか？ また、「パスワード付きではないPDF」などは、同じディレクトリにあるにも関わらず、問題が起きません。

Comment: ファイルを開く＝読み込む権限はファイル自体の `r` ビット、ファイルの移動や削除はディレクトリの `w` や `x` ビットに依存するので別設定です。でもなんだか単純に当該ファイルを別プロセスが開いたままなだけのような気がしてきました。一度 `lsof` コマンドを試してみてください。

Comment: なるほど。rの権限が無ければそのような状況がありえるのですね。「当該ファイルを別プロセスが開いたまま」のときは、そのファイルの移動や削除はできるのですか？

Comment: パスワード付のファイルを開くには、パスワードが必要です。どのようにしてファイルを開いているのですか？

Comment: Javaアプリケーション上では、`FileInputStream`のコンストラクタで開きます。CentOS上では、`strings`コマンドで開けるかどうか確認しました。

Comment: ディレクトリの権限設定を確認しました。`rwxrwxrwx`です。本文に追記してあります。

Comment: 問題の一時ファイルに対して lsattr コマンドを実行した結果を教えていただけますか？

Comment: 「ディレクトリの権限設定を確認しました」　すみません間違えました。`rwxrwxrwt`です。

Comment: `lsattr`コマンドは、「許可されていない操作です」のエラーが起きて実行できません。

Comment: 「許可されていない操作です」のエラーは、ファイルの中身を見て判定しているようです。本文に追加調査の結果を追記しました。

Comment: 本当に中身の問題なら、バイナリエディタで"%PDF-"を戻してみると再発することになりますが、どうでしょうか。あとは仮想マシン等で別のLinux環境を作ってみてそっちで試してみるとか・・・試しにパスワード付きPDFを作ってCentOS7でstringsとかやってみましたが、やはり何も問題はありませんでした。

Comment: SELinux の無効化やログの確認はお済みでしょうか。

Comment: SELinuxは無効になっています

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mcafee Virus Scanがインストールされていたようで、その影響であることが判明しました。
（Mcafeeを無効化することで、エラーが起きなくなったため）